# How to PARTITION BY a query accepting NULL values?

Tags: sql, postgresql, partition-by

I have a query that I need to use `PARTITION BY` with 2 fields. I'm doing it like:

```
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER()
    OVER (PARTITION BY
            id, country_id
        ORDER BY
            id, country_id) AS row_number
    FROM
        cities
    ...
```

The problem is that `country_id`, the second aggregated field used in `PARTITION BY`, can be `NULL` and I need `ROW_NUMBER()` to be summed up.

`row_number()` sums up only if there's a record with the same `id`  and `country_id` in the result set. I want it to be summed up if there's a record with the same `id` and `country_id` or the same `id` and `country_id` is `NULL`.

Is there a way to do so?

Comment: sample data and desired results would help.  What does "aggregate the `row_number()` mean?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the coalesce as shown below:

```
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER()
    OVER (PARTITION BY
            id, Coalesce(country_id,0)) AS row_number
    FROM
        cities
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

It makes no difference if one of the values is `NULL`.  On the other hand, it isn't useful to order by the same columns.  In Postgres, the `order by` is optional, so you can just do:

```
row_number() over (partition by id, country_id)
```

Comment: `row_number()` sums up only if there's a record with the same `id`  and `country_id` in the result set. I want it to be summed up if there's a record with the same `id` and `country_id` or the same `id` and `country_id` is `NULL`.

Comment: @vnbrs . . . As I've already asked, your question needs sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1):

try REPLACE NULL

```
SELECT
ROW_NUMBER()
OVER (PARTITION BY
        id, ISNULL(country_id,-1)
    ORDER BY
        id, ISNULL(country_id,-1)) AS row_number
FROM
    cities
...
```